# Is there a way to remove this green flare?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, color-correction

I took a picture where the sun was just to the left of the subject with my mobile camera. Due to the sun I couldn't see my screen after I'd taken the photo and didn't realise there was a slight green streak running diagonally across the screen.

I imagine I'd have to mask the streak and apply curves adjustments, however are there other ways to remove this streak?

The original image is a lot larger, this one has been sized down and compressed a little.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video tutorial is up here: [60 Seconds: How to remove green flare](https://youtu.be/EThlqgIyF64) (please consider subscribing)

1. Convert the image to Lab color mode
2. Create a Curves Adjustment
3. In the B Channel put two points in there - one on the green and one off it. You can use the top left tool that looks like an up/down arrow with a finger on it if it helps you. They are very close together so you might need to put the whichever you do second a little further away for it to work and then you can move it in once you have it on the Curve. Then just *level* those two points. Congrats, now the amount of green is even and the streak is gone. No masking or complex things needed.

[image]

If you feel the image is a bit too red as a result just do another Curve and adjust the A channel without adding new points to it, I also added a tiny bit of yellow in the B channel. Notice how very subtle my adjustment is in the Curve:

[image]

Comment: congrats nice solution.. 2 questions: 1) why did you chose Lab color? 2) why is it only affecting the light streak and not the Whole image? i was expecting a layer mask or something like that, but there was no need.

Comment: @sharkyenergy I was writing an answer in the comments for you but just answering that is getting quite long. Would also benefit from more screenshots I think. When I have a bit of free time i'll either make an edit to this or create a new Q&A to further explain some of this for you. Or if you want to make a new a question asking about why this works that would be good too.

Comment: @sharkyenergy in the meantime at least for the Why in more general terms you can see my explanation here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/76824/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-using-lab-color